How do I run a LLM on multiple GPUs?
I am trying to run Mistral-7b across multiple GPUs, as I have a large number of prompts. I am using a cluster, which provides usage of up to 4 GPUs. However, only one of them is used for inference.
model_name = 'mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2'

# Load the model and tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

# Check if multiple GPUs are available
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print(f"Using {torch.cuda.device_count()} GPUs")
    model = DataParallel(model)
else:
    print("Using single GPU or CPU")

# Move model to GPU(s)
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

# Load prompts from DataFrame
prompts = prompts_df["prompt"].tolist()  

# Function to generate response
def generate_response(prompt, max_new_tokens=30):
    inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model.module.generate(**inputs,
                                 max_new_tokens=max_new_tokens,
                                 pad_token_id=tokenizer.pad_token_id,
                                 eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
    return tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

# Process prompts in batches
batch_size = 32  # Increased batch size, adjust based on your GPU memory
responses = []
for i in tqdm(range(0, len(prompts), batch_size)):
    batch = prompts[i:i+batch_size]
    responses.extend([generate_response(prompt) for prompt in batch])

Performing this code, with nvidia-smi I see that GPU0 is 98% occupied, while GPU1 is 0%.
I hope someone can help me out here. Using only one GPU would take way too long.
I read that with mode.module.generate this could be fixed, but this did not work for me here.
